# In Git, how do you rebase from your feature branch when the source branch history has been changed?

Tags: git

In my case, I branched off from branch `master` and I have done work on it since. However, then `master` squashed a lot of commits and now the last common commit - the one that I originally branched off from - doesn't exist anymore.

Is there a way to rebase the `master` branch into my own with the least amount of pain possible? Ideally, I'd like my feature branch history to be

```
Current HEAD of master branch -> my changes (squashed or not)
```

Currently, trying to simply do `git rebase origin/master` brings up a ton of file changes that happened in `master` but not in my local branch.

Comment: That's what rebasing is--rewriting history as though you had branched from the _new_ state of master--and why I tend to avoid it. Can't you just merge in master? An alternative might be to create a new branch from the updated master and cherry-pick your commits onto that.

Comment: Drop the now-squashed commits between the last shared commit and the first commit of yours, then rebase from there?

Comment: It sound like https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your feature branch contains commits no longer on master, so a rebase ‘attributes’ these commits to your feature branch and tries to apply them on to master. Therefore you need to limit the range of commits that should be applied.

- If the point at which you created your feature branch is still in your reflog, you can use `--fork-point` to let Git automatically work out the correct rebase.

  ```
  git rebase --fork-point origin/master
  ```
- You can manually specify how far along the branch should be being rebased onto master.

  ```
  git rebase <hash-of-first-feature-commit> <your-feature-branch> --onto origin/master
  ```